# Accessing necessary field json golang

Tags: json, api, go

I've been trying to access field from third party api.
For example the json response from third party api is like this:

```
{
    "request_id": "bba3b69370774f87bed0e70398a97f45",
    "account_id": "2c1cd618",
    "number": "6289523686433"
}
```

I want to get request_id only
can I create interface only like this:

```
type Response struct {
   RequestID string json:"request_id"
}
```

and then do this:

```
var resp Response
json.Unmarshal(body,&resp)
```

Is it possible to do this? Or do I need to make all field of response body in Response struct to be able to unmarshall?
Thanks

Comment: You already have the code. Why don't you try it?

Comment: I don't have the api key and api secret, so I can't tested it on my own

Comment: You can "hard-code" the source JSON text for the time of the test.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

From the `json.Unmarshal` docs

> By default, object keys which don't have a corresponding struct field are ignored (see Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields for an alternative).

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

Here is a runnable example, showing it working as expected

https://play.golang.org/p/PwnSj03hnEV